# How to drag (move tool) an object in a drawing in Photoshop if it includes several layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Tell me, please.
For example, I need to move a painted ear. Just move it a little bit. But this ear is drawn on several layers + shadows , etc .
I tried combining layers. But then the whole drawing is transferred, and not the selected object. Or is a piece of the image transferred only on the selected layer.

However, the previous ear will remain in the same place. And I have to erase on each layer where the ear is drawn

Answer (score 2):

Layer management is an important part of digital creation.

If you had drawn the ears each on their own layer, this wouldn't be a problem. But with layers spanning many areas, you generally need to cut/paste selections to create individual layers. Then you can highlight the layers you need and move them without altering other areas.

Basically...

- Draw a selection around the ear
- Highlight Layer 1, hit <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. This will cut the content from layer 1 and move it to it's own layer (without moving any pixels)
- Repeat for each layer that has part of the ear drawn on it.

The result *should* be several new layers that only contain parts of the ear. You can then merge or *group* these layers and move them without moving anything else.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Yes, indeed, I have one ear, which is painted on many layers!

Comment: I will try to do your advice